# WSO2 Identity Server Cannot see options in userstore, policyadministration etc

Tags: wso2, xacml, wso2-identity-server

Hey i have just installed the WSO2 Idenity Server on my windows 7 system (localhost) to test the XACML features.

But is see nothing in the userstore, policyadministration and other features on the dashboard... any suggestions ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5im6X.png
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBZ9W.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixxed.... i used JDK 1.8 instead of 1.6/1.7.

Sorry with 1.6 it works fine.